# Access view like a another View when reuse layout multiple times in single layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a app In which I reuse a child-layout multiple times in another layout.
In my child layout there is only 1 button.
My question is that..
How can I access a View of child layout as a different.

like for example I access child layout 3 time in Parent layout.
then it shows 3 buttons in Parent layout on run time.
I want to call different activities from these buttons.

```
 My child layout


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/chemistry" />

</RelativeLayout>

My Parent Layout
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/login_bg" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="470dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/lol"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >



    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

```
  Java Code-- 
LinearLayout rl= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lol);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)           this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ArrayList<String> as= getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("dis");
    Object[] mstring= as.toArray();
int x=  mstring.length;
for (int i=0;i<x; i++ ){

    View childLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.despage,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.despage));
               rl.addView(childLayout);
```

Comment: do it in code, or use `include` which ever is appropriate

Comment: can you paste code what you have done?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an id to each include like this

```
<include android:id=”@+id/child1”
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”match_parent”
         layout=”@layout/child”/>
<include android:id=”@+id/child2”
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”match_parent”
         layout=”@layout/child”/>
<include android:id=”@+id/child3”
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”match_parent”
         layout=”@layout/child”/>
```

Then from the Activity you can retrieve each child and its content with:

```
View child1 = findViewById(R.id.child1);
Button button1 = child1.findViewById(R.id.someButtonInsideChildLayout);
View child2 = findViewById(R.id.child2);
Button button2 = child2.findViewById(R.id.someButtonInsideChildLayout);
..
```

Probably you can solve your problem in a better way using styles (eg. one style in values/styles.xml applied to 3 buttons inside the main layout).

Edit (after code attached to the question)
You can access each button inside the for loop with

```
Button button = childLayout.findViewById(R.id.bt1);
```

Comment: Can I add ID pragmatically? 
because the number of reusing layout is not fix.

Comment: Looking at your code it doesn't seem that you need IDs. Just call findViewById(R.id.bt1) method on "childLayout" object.

Comment: It seem like I have only one button but shows 3 times in different position Parent Layout. when i call it with on click listener then how to find that which one is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

parent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/child" 
    android:text="Button 1">
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/child" 
    android:text="Button 2"
    >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/child"
    android:text="Button 3" >
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

child.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked on button 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked on    button2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```